# Item selection in combobox not working

Tags: select, combobox, vaadin

I have problem with selecting value in vaadin combobox which I have filled with objects that I get from EJB3 layer. I have overwritten `toString()` to the class so that combobox shows desired property instead of serial value of object.

Tried with

```
cb.setValue(object)
```

and

```
cb.select(object)
```

and it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Code that gets data from DB:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Kontakt> findAll() {
    log.debug("getting all Kontakts");
    try {
        List<Kontakt> instance = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Kontakt.findAll").getResultList();
        log.debug("get successful");
            return instance;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("get failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

Implementation in Vaadin :

```
cbUstanova = new ComboBox("Ustanova");
cbUstanova.addItems(ustanovaEJB.findAll());
cbUstanova.setRequired(true);
```

Comment: How are equals and hashCode implemented on your objects?

Comment: Yes as Henri mentioned, check if `hashcode()` & `equals()` is implemented also I believe there are better ways to show a value rather than using `toString()`

Comment: How do you populate the ComboBox? Can you show your code so we see the class

Comment: check hashCode() and equals() implementation. then it should work

Comment: You were right. After i implemented hashCode and equals in Entity classes everything is ok. Thanks.